# C++ regular expressions work in GCC but not in CLANG

Tags: c++, regex, string, debugging

**Minimal example**:
This code prints `1` if compiled with GCC, but it crashes if compiled with CLANG:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout <<regex_match(
                     "3.14159265359",
                     regex("(^(\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z])*$)|((\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z])+\\.("
                           "\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z])*$)")) <<endl;
}
```

What's going on?

**Original post**:
Hey, guys! I am trying to port a [program](https://flatassembler.github.io/compiler.html) I've written in JavaScript to C++, because I hear it's a significantly better language than JavaScript is. However, I've run into a (to me) very weird problem, namely, that what I've made thus far works in GCC 9.3.0, but not in CLANG 10.0.0.
File `AECforWebAssembly.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "parser.cpp"
#include "tests.cpp"
#include "tokenizer.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  cout << "Running the tests..." << endl;
  runTests();
  cout << "All the tests passed." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

File `TreeNode.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#pragma once

class TreeNode {
public:
  std::vector<TreeNode> children;
  std::string text;
  int lineNumber, columnNumber;
  TreeNode() { lineNumber = columnNumber = 0; }
  TreeNode(std::string newText, int newLine, int newColumn) {
    text = newText;
    lineNumber = newLine;
    columnNumber = newColumn;
  }
  static std::vector<TreeNode>
  tokenize(std::string input); // See "tokenizer.cpp" for the implementation.
  static std::string JSONifyArrayOfTokens(
      std::vector<TreeNode> tokenizedString) { // For debugging the tokenizer.
    std::string ret = "[";
    if (!tokenizedString.size())
      return "[]";
    for (int i = 0; i < tokenizedString.size(); i++)
      if (i != tokenizedString.size() - 1)
        ret += "'" + tokenizedString[i].text + "',";
      else
        ret += "'" + tokenizedString[i].text + "']";
    return ret;
  }
  static std::vector<TreeNode> parse(
      std::vector<TreeNode> input); // See "parser.cpp" for the implementation.
};
```

File `parser.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "TreeNode.cpp"

std::vector<TreeNode> TreeNode::parse(std::vector<TreeNode> input) {
  throw std::string("Parser is not yet implemented!");
}
```

File `tests.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "TreeNode.cpp"

struct test { // When the debugger doesn't work, "cassert" doesn't help a lot.
  std::string input, expectedResult;
};

void tokenizerTests() {
  std::vector<test> tests(
      {{"5+5", "['5','+','5']"},
       {"5+5=10", "['5','+','5','=','10']"},
       {"structureName.structureMember/3.14159265359",
        "['structureName','.','structureMember','/','3.14159265359']"},
       {"sin(pi/2)=1", "['sin(','pi','/','2',')','=','1']"},
       {"'A'+2='C'", "['65','+','2','=','67']"},
       {"a:=a+1; //Some random comment.\nb:=b-1;",
        "['a',':=','a','+','1',';','b',':=','b','-','1',';']"},
       {"/*This should be tokenized into\nan empty string*/", "[]"},
       {"a/*Randomly\ninserted\ncomment.*/+/*Another\nrandom\ncomment*/b",
        "['a','+','b']"}});
  for (int i = 0; i < tests.size(); i++) {
    std::string result =
        TreeNode::JSONifyArrayOfTokens(TreeNode::tokenize(tests[i].input));
    if (result != tests[i].expectedResult) {
      std::cerr << "Internal compiler error: Tokenizer test failed: \""
                << tests[i].input << "\" tokenizes into \"" << result
                << "\" instead of to \"" << tests[i].expectedResult << "\"!"
                << std::endl;
      std::exit(1);
    }
  }
}

void runTests() { tokenizerTests(); }
```

File `tokenizer.cpp` (this is almost certainly where the error lies):

```cpp
#include "TreeNode.cpp"

std::vector<TreeNode> TreeNode::tokenize(std::string input) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
  std::cerr << "DEBUG: Tokenizing the string \"" << input << "\"..."
            << std::endl;
#endif
  using std::regex;
  using std::regex_match;
  using std::string;
  auto tokenizedExpression = std::vector<TreeNode>();
  int currentLine = 1, currentColumn = 1;
  bool areWeInAString = false, areWeInAComment = false;
  string stringDelimiter, commentDelimiter;
  try {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
      std::cerr << "DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #" << i << ": '"
                << input[i] << "'." << std::endl;
      if (areWeInAString)
        std::cerr << "DEBUG: We are in a string." << std::endl;
      if (areWeInAComment)
        std::cerr << "DEBUG: We are in a comment." << std::endl;
#endif
      if (tokenizedExpression.size() == 0) {
        if (input.size() - i > 2 and
            (input.substr(i, 2) == "//" or input.substr(i, 2) == "/*")) {
          areWeInAComment = true;
          commentDelimiter = input.substr(i, 2);
          tokenizedExpression.push_back(TreeNode(string(), 1, 1));
          currentColumn++;
          continue;
        }
        tokenizedExpression.push_back(TreeNode(input.substr(i, 1), 1, 1));
        currentColumn++;
        if (input[i] == '"' or input[i] == '\'') {
          areWeInAString = true;
          stringDelimiter = input.substr(i, 1);
        }
      } else if ((input[i] == '"' or input[i] == '\'') and !areWeInAComment) {
        if (areWeInAString and stringDelimiter == input.substr(i, 1) and
            (i == 0 or input[i - 1] != '\\')) {
          tokenizedExpression.back().text.push_back(input[i]);
          tokenizedExpression.push_back(
              TreeNode(string(), currentLine, currentColumn));
          currentColumn++;
          areWeInAString = false;
        } else {
          currentColumn++;
          areWeInAString = true;
          stringDelimiter = input.substr(i, 1);
          tokenizedExpression.push_back(
              TreeNode(input.substr(i, 1), currentLine, currentColumn));
        }
      } else if (input.size() - i > 2 and
                 (input.substr(i, 2) == "//" or input.substr(i, 2) == "/*") and
                 !areWeInAString and !areWeInAComment) {
        areWeInAComment = true;
        commentDelimiter = input.substr(i, 2);
      } else if (input[i] == '\n') { // If we came to the end of a line.
        if (areWeInAString) {
          std::cerr << "Line " << currentLine << ", Column "
                    << tokenizedExpression.back().columnNumber
                    << ", Tokenizer error: Unterminated string literal!"
                    << std::endl;
          areWeInAString = false;
        }
        if (areWeInAComment and commentDelimiter == "//")
          areWeInAComment = false;
        else if (areWeInAComment) {
          currentLine++;
          currentColumn = 1;
          continue;
        }
        currentLine++;
        currentColumn = 1;
        tokenizedExpression.push_back(
            TreeNode(string(), currentLine, currentColumn));
      } else if (regex_match(input.substr(i, 1),
                             regex("\\s")) and
                 !areWeInAString and
                 !areWeInAComment) { // If we came to some other whitespace.
        currentColumn++;
        tokenizedExpression.push_back(
            TreeNode(string(), currentLine, currentColumn));
      } else if (regex_match(input.substr(i, 1), regex("\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z]|_")) and
                 regex_match(
                     tokenizedExpression.back().text,
                     regex("(^(\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z])*$)|((\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z])+\\.("
                           "\\d|[a-z]|[A-Z])*$)")) and
                 !areWeInAString and !areWeInAComment) // Names and numbers
      {
        currentColumn++;
        tokenizedExpression.back().text += input[i];
      } else if (input[i] == '.' and
                 regex_match(tokenizedExpression.back().text,
                             regex("^\\d+$")) and
                 !areWeInAString and
                 !areWeInAComment) // If we are currently
                                   // tokenizing a number, a dot
                                   // character is a decimal point.
      {
        currentColumn++;
        tokenizedExpression.back().text += input[i];
      } else if (!areWeInAString and !areWeInAComment) {
        currentColumn++;
        tokenizedExpression.push_back(
            TreeNode(input.substr(i, 1), currentLine, currentColumn));
      } else if (areWeInAString and !areWeInAComment) {
        currentColumn++;
        tokenizedExpression.back().text += input[i];
      } else if (areWeInAComment and commentDelimiter == "/*" and
                 input.size() - i > 2 and input.substr(i, 2) == "*/" and
                 !areWeInAString) {
        areWeInAComment = false;
        currentColumn += 2;
        tokenizedExpression.push_back(
            TreeNode(string(), currentLine, currentColumn));
        i++;
      } else if (!areWeInAString and areWeInAComment) {
        currentColumn++;
      } else {
        std::cerr << "Line " << currentLine << ", Column " << currentColumn
                  << ", Internal compiler error: Tokenizer is in the "
                     "forbidden state!"
                  << std::endl;
      }
    }
    for (auto iterator = tokenizedExpression.begin();
         iterator < tokenizedExpression.end(); iterator++)
      if (iterator->text.size() == 3 and iterator->text.substr(0, 1) == "'" and
          iterator->text.substr(2, 1) == "'")
        iterator->text = std::to_string(int(iterator->text[1]));
    for (auto iterator = tokenizedExpression.begin();
         iterator < tokenizedExpression.end(); iterator++)
      if (regex_match(iterator->text, regex("^\\s*$"))) // Delete empty nodes.
      {
        iterator--;
        tokenizedExpression.erase(iterator + 1);
      }
    for (int i = 1; i < tokenizedExpression.size(); i++)
      if ((tokenizedExpression[i].text ==
               "(" or // Mark the names of functions...
           tokenizedExpression[i].text ==
               "[") and //...and arrays with ending '(' or '['
          regex_match(
              tokenizedExpression[i - 1].text.substr(0, 1), //...for the parser.
              regex("_|[a-z]|[A-Z]"))) {
        tokenizedExpression[i - 1].text += tokenizedExpression[i].text;
        tokenizedExpression.erase(tokenizedExpression.begin() + i);
      }
    for (int i = 1; i < tokenizedExpression.size(); i++)
      if (tokenizedExpression[i].text == "=" and
          tokenizedExpression[i - 1].text ==
              ":") // The ":=" assignment operator.
      {
        tokenizedExpression[i - 1].text = ":=";
        tokenizedExpression.erase(tokenizedExpression.begin() + i);
      }
  } catch (std::regex_error error) {
    std::cerr << "Internal compiler error in tokenizer: " << error.what() << ":"
              << error.code() << std::endl;
    return std::vector<TreeNode>();
  }
#ifndef NDEBUG
  std::cerr << "DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string \"" << input << "\"."
            << std::endl;
#endif
  return tokenizedExpression;
}
```

When compiled with GCC and run, the program outputs:

```
Running the tests...
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "5+5"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: '+'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: '5'.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "5+5".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "5+5=10"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: '+'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: '='.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: '1'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: '0'.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "5+5=10".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "structureName.structureMember/3.14159265359"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: 's'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: 't'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: 'r'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: 'u'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: 'c'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: 't'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #6: 'u'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #7: 'r'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #8: 'e'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #9: 'N'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #10: 'a'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #11: 'm'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #12: 'e'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #13: '.'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #14: 's'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #15: 't'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #16: 'r'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #17: 'u'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #18: 'c'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #19: 't'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #20: 'u'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #21: 'r'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #22: 'e'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #23: 'M'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #24: 'e'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #25: 'm'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #26: 'b'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #27: 'e'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #28: 'r'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #29: '/'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #30: '3'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #31: '.'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #32: '1'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #33: '4'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #34: '1'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #35: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #36: '9'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #37: '2'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #38: '6'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #39: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #40: '3'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #41: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #42: '9'.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "structureName.structureMember/3.14159265359".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "sin(pi/2)=1"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: 's'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: 'i'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: 'n'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: '('.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: 'p'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: 'i'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #6: '/'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #7: '2'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #8: ')'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #9: '='.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #10: '1'.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "sin(pi/2)=1".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "'A'+2='C'"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: '''.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: 'A'.
DEBUG: We are in a string.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: '''.
DEBUG: We are in a string.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: '+'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: '2'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: '='.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #6: '''.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #7: 'C'.
DEBUG: We are in a string.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #8: '''.
DEBUG: We are in a string.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "'A'+2='C'".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "a:=a+1; //Some random comment.
b:=b-1;"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: 'a'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: ':'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: '='.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: 'a'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: '+'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: '1'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #6: ';'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #7: ' '.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #8: '/'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #9: '/'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #10: 'S'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #11: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #12: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #13: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #14: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #15: 'r'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #16: 'a'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #17: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #18: 'd'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #19: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #20: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #21: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #22: 'c'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #23: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #24: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #25: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #26: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #27: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #28: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #29: '.'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #30: '
'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #31: 'b'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #32: ':'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #33: '='.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #34: 'b'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #35: '-'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #36: '1'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #37: ';'.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "a:=a+1; //Some random comment.
b:=b-1;".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "/*This should be tokenized into
an empty string*/"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: '/'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: '*'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: 'T'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: 'h'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: 'i'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: 's'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #6: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #7: 's'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #8: 'h'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #9: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #10: 'u'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #11: 'l'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #12: 'd'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #13: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #14: 'b'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #15: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #16: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #17: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #18: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #19: 'k'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #20: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #21: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #22: 'i'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #23: 'z'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #24: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #25: 'd'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #26: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #27: 'i'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #28: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #29: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #30: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #31: '
'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #32: 'a'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #33: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #34: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #35: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #36: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #37: 'p'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #38: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #39: 'y'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #40: ' '.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #41: 's'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #42: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #43: 'r'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #44: 'i'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #45: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #46: 'g'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #47: '*'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #48: '/'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "/*This should be tokenized into
an empty string*/".
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "a/*Randomly
inserted
comment.*/+/*Another
random
comment*/b"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: 'a'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: '/'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #2: '*'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #3: 'R'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #4: 'a'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #5: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #6: 'd'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #7: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #8: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #9: 'l'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #10: 'y'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #11: '
'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #12: 'i'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #13: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #14: 's'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #15: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #16: 'r'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #17: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #18: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #19: 'd'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #20: '
'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #21: 'c'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #22: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #23: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #24: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #25: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #26: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #27: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #28: '.'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #29: '*'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #31: '+'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #32: '/'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #33: '*'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #34: 'A'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #35: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #36: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #37: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #38: 'h'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #39: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #40: 'r'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #41: '
'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #42: 'r'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #43: 'a'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #44: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #45: 'd'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #46: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #47: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #48: '
'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #49: 'c'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #50: 'o'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #51: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #52: 'm'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #53: 'e'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #54: 'n'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #55: 't'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #56: '*'.
DEBUG: We are in a comment.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #58: 'b'.
DEBUG: Finished tokenizing the string "a/*Randomly
inserted
comment.*/+/*Another
random
comment*/b".
All the tests passed.
```

However, when compiled with CLANG and run, it outputs:

```
Running the tests...
DEBUG: Tokenizing the string "5+5"...
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #0: '5'.
DEBUG: Now we are tokenizing the character #1: '+'.
Internal compiler error in tokenizer: regex_error:2
Internal compiler error: Tokenizer test failed: "5+5" tokenizes into "[]" instead of to "['5','+','5']"!
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
By the way, which IDE would you recommend me as a begineer in C++? You know, something that will work out of the box. I am using Oracle Linux, and I've tried GNAT Programming Studio, but I haven't managed to get it to compile C programs, yet alone C++ programs. I've also tried to use Eclipse, but I haven't managed to compile this program in it. I've tried to use Code::Blocks, however, the only way to run it on Linux is to compile it from source, which I failed to do. Now I am using VIM, just like I was doing when programming in JavaScript. I switched to C++ precisely because I wanted the IDE experience.

Comment: Why do you have a `#pragma once` in a *source* file?

Comment: @JesperJuhl What's wrong with that? Look, I come from JavaScript and I am fairly new to C++.

Comment: That's a lot of code you have here. You should provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @FlatAssembler What do you think `#pragma once`  does?

Comment: @eerorika It makes sure you don't include that file twice in the source code, as far as I know.

Comment: @FlatAssembler And the file that you put that pragma contains definitions that must not be defined in more than one file. Thus there is no point to include it into another file. Thus the pragma is pointless.

Comment: @eerorika Well, if that was the error, the code wouldn't even compile. It compiles in both GCC and CLANG, but it doesn't work in CLANG.

Comment: @FlatAssembler Why would that mean that the code wouldn't compile?

Comment: @FlatAssembler You should not be `#include`ing .cpp files in the first place (only header files), so the `pragma` is pointless. If if actually *does* something it's because you are doing something else wrong. Like; `#include "parser.cpp"
#include "tests.cpp"
#include "tokenizer.cpp"` - That's just straight up *not* the way to do it.

Comment: @eerorika As far as I understand it, if preprocessor omits some file due to preprocessor error, that will result in either compiler error or a linker error. It wouldn't result in something like this.

Comment: @JesperJuhl And what's the alternative to including ".cpp" files in this case?

Comment: @FlatAssembler "And what's the alternative to including ".cpp" files" - You split your code into headers (usually named `.h` or `.hh`) that contain only declarations (and those need header guards or `#pragma once` to prevent multiple inclusion)  and source files (usually named `.cc` or `.cpp`) that contain the definitions. You then `#include` the header files where you need to access the declarations and you compile the source files into object files that are then linked together into the final executable. That's the nutshell explanation.

Comment: @FlatAssembler, Firstly, use header files as others have said in the comment. Secondly, post minimal code required to reproduce your problem, not this lot. For this case, I believe you can do so by just identifying for which regex and string, regex_match throws an exception. By output, I am guessing the string is `"5+5"`. Find the regex. :)

Comment: @brc-dd OK, I believe I've found the regex, so I've edited my post.

Comment: @FlatAssembler Unable to reproduce. Prints `1` for me on `clang` also.  https://wandbox.org/permlink/METKJRWO7tBRrXsj

Comment: @brc-dd Then I guess I improperly installed CLANG on Oracle Linux. `clang --version` prints: `clang: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by clang)
clang version 10.0.0 `
`Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`
`Thread model: posix`
`InstalledDir: /home/teo.samarzija/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin`
Any idea what I am doing wrong with that?

Comment: @FlatAssembler It works for `clang v10.0.0` also. [See here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/METKJRWO7tBRrXsj). Edit: I've checked on every version since 3.1 of clang. Your code works fine for C++11 or above.

Comment: @brc-dd Well, oddly, on my machine (Oracle Linux 7) it doesn't work even when compiled with "-static".

Comment: @FlatAssembler Can't comment then. I able to successfully even on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GEYcqx).

Comment: Works for me using clang 6.0 as well.

Comment: You can delete the "Original post" section, if the "minimal example" is really a minimal example.